# User authentication with Nuxt, Typescript, GraphQL and refresh tokens

Tags: typescript, authentication, graphql, jwt, nuxt.js

I am developing an application. I've created a GraphQL API for Backend, which uses JWT and refresh tokens for user authentication. And an application made with Nuxt JS and Typescript for the frontend. But I didn't find much about how to do that. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the "easy way" is use [nuxt-apollo](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module), it has a learning curve but it'll facilitate a lot your development

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is that you can use the Nuxt/auth modules to get the JWT and use it with your graph query.

I'm thinking to use this method too.

The reason is because nuxt/auth has many people are using it and you can find the solution on the internet so easily.

But the code is harder to maintain.

You also can use nuxt apollo to create the authentication with a login query.

It is easier to maintain just using one strategy and concept.

I use Strapi and graphql for my backend API.